# jquery difference between "on click element" and "find element" on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors, difference

is there any difference between this both selectors in combination with a click event?

```
$("#container").find(".element").on("click",function(){

})

$("#container").on("click", ".element",function(){

})
```

For me I think technically the effect and consequence will be the same?
Thank you

Comment: Second works for dynamically added `.element`. First does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same.

The first example using `find().on()` looks for the `.element` class in the DOM and adds the event handler to it. It will not work for any elements with that class that are added to the DOM later in the page lifecycle.

The second example using `on()` with a selector is a delegated event handler, and will therefore work for all matching elements in the DOM as well as those added later.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear. What if when no other content is added later / the DOM and its elements are static? Which one of these should I prefer?

Comment: Glad to help. Either is fine for the case you describe. The latter adds a single event handler, but relies on event bubbling in order to work.